# Затемнение прочих select'ов при работе с одним select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеет несколько select-элементов в форме такого вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с соответствующим кодом:

```
<label for="districts"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="districts" name="districts">
    <option value="191"></option>
    <option value="195"></option>
    ...
</select>
<label for="region"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="region" name="region">
    <option value="191"></option>
    <option value="195"></option>
    ...
</select>
<label for="city"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" name="city">
    <option value="191"></option>
    <option value="195"></option>
    ...
</select>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как затемнить/сделать неактивными прочие select-элементы при работе с одним, пример на картинке. Соответственно, если элемент не выбран в select, прочие select'ы снова становятся активны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно еще вот так попробовать...

```js
$("option").click(function(){
 if($(this).parent().is(':disabled')){
 $("[multiple=multiple]").prop('disabled', false);
 $("option").prop("selected", false);
 }
});

$("select").on('change', function(){
 $("[multiple=multiple]").prop('disabled', true);
 $(this).prop("disabled", false);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="districts"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="districts" name="districts">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>
<label for="region"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="region" name="region">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>

<label for="city"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" name="city">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Можно делать все `select`, кроме того, с которым сейчас работаем неактивными. Однако, для "вывода" из `disabled` необходимо обернуть `select` в `div` (например), так как события на неактивных элементах игнорируются браузерами.

Также можно и не использовать `disabled`, а добавлять/удалять некий класс ([.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) / [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) / [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)), который будет стилизовать "не активные" `select-ы` необходимым образом.

```js
// Если кликнули по "обёртке", в которой есть select
$(".select:has(select)").on("click", function() {
  $("select").attr("disabled", true); // все select - disabled
  $("select", this).removeAttr("disabled"); // "наш" select не disabled
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="districts"></label>
<div class="select">
  <select multiple="multiple" id="districts" name="districts">
      <option value="191">first</option>
      <option value="195">second</option>
      <option value="191">first</option>
      <option value="195">second</option>
  </select>
</div>
<label for="region"></label>

<div class="select">
  <select multiple="multiple" id="region" name="region">
      <option value="191">first</option>
      <option value="195">second</option>
      <option value="191">first</option>
      <option value="195">second</option>
  </select>
</div>

<label for="city"></label>
<div class="select">
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" name="city">
    <option value="191">first</option>
    <option value="195">second</option>
    <option value="191">first</option>
     <option value="195">second</option>
</select>
</div>
```

C классом всё проще. Никаких "обёрток" не требуется.

```js
$("select").on("click", function() {
  $("select").addClass("disabled");
  $(this).removeClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="districts"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="districts" name="districts">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>
<label for="region"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="region" name="region">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>

<label for="city"></label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="city" name="city">
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
  <option value="191">first</option>
  <option value="195">second</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Только прочие селекты остаются доступны для выбора, и человек может с ними работать. А если их скрывать hide'ом?

Comment: Вообще очень похоже, что Вы делаете что-то вроде такого: [link](http://webersoft.ru/lab/sqlcelect/). Тогда это совсем другая история.

Comment: Да, похоже. Но изначально логика заложена вот такая странная - я должен выбрать хотя бы один селект, относительно вашего примера неважно какой: страну, область, город - он бы и считался моим выбором